# File size validation laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Why do I get the error message `validation.uploaded` instead of proper error message on validating the size of an image. Following is the rule I am using for validation.

```
'file' => 'required|max:1024|dimensions:max_width=275,min_width=200,height=75'
```

For dimensions the message is ok. But, the message for validating the size (KB) is displaying weird message.

Comment: Please share the view file content and exact error

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the upload itself, not with Laravel validation rules. Maybe you are trying to upload a larger file which is denied by PHP configuration. Please check for the following fields in **php.ini**:

- upload_max_size
- post_max_size

Comment: thanks @Szika. i am uploading a file having size less than 1MB